# Big O in Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I was reading an article and came across the following :

Informally, O(g(n)) can be defined as the set of mathematical functions that contains all functions that don’t “grow faster” than g(n). Thus, all functions below are in the set O(n²):
`f(n) = n²+3n + 2, f(n) = n log(n), f(n) = 3n+1` 
.
Can please anyone tell me how *f(n) = n²+3n + 2* **grows faster** than g(n)?

Comment: Do you know the definitions, are you familiar with the math behind the O notation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Comment: You're asking how n²+3n + 2 grows faster than n². Is that really what you meant to ask?

Answer (score 1):

> Can please anyone tell me how f(n) = n²+3n + 2 grows faster than g(n)?

Here is one way to understand it (a bit informal, but I find it more intuitive).

Let `L` be limit as `n` goes to infinity of `f(n)/g(n)`

If `L` is infinity then `f(n)` grows faster than `g(n)` (numerator overwhelms denominator).

If `L` is `0` then `f(n)` grows slower than `g(n)` (denominator overwhelms numerator)

If `L` is finite number then they have same (comparable) growth rates.

Answer (score 0):

We can define O(g(n)) as the following set:

> O(g(n)) = { f(n) ∶ ∃ c > 0 and n0 > 0 | 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ c ⋅ g(n), ∀n ≥ n0 }

This means O(g(n)) is the set of all functions f(n) which grow slower than g(n) for some constant c and for n ≥ n0. In order to find n0 and c we use a justification like the following:

> n²+3n + 2 ≤ n² + 3n² + 2n²
> n²+3n + 2 ≤ 6n² for c = 6 and n ≥ 1

Now if you just use g(n) = n² obviously f(n) = n² + 3n + 2 will grow faster than g(n); but by choosing the value of *c* correctly g(n) will grow faster than f(n) for n ≥ n0.

Comment: I highly doubt OP understands that. And it does not really answer the question why f(n) grows faster than g(n).

Comment: I think given the description it is obvious why f(n) might grow faster than g(n) for some values of c

Comment: I agree its obvious - but if it were obvious to OP the question would not have been posted. It should not have been posted but here we are...

Comment: Agree to disagree